# Using async configuration in AngularJS directive

Tags: asynchronous, angularjs

I have a directive that looks at configuration to figure out what template to use. It used to work great; I had a Config service that just returned an object with config values, and then I did something like this:

```
if (Config.Values.ReleaseVersion < 1.0) {
  template = 'partials/pagebeta.html';
}
else {
  template = 'partials/page.html';
}
templateUrl: template
```

Recently a problem was introduced. My Config service has to get values from a json file. Now because getting config is async, I am now passing back a promise from the Config service. This is creating problems for me in my directive - I can't do this:

```
var template;
Config.then(function(config) {
  if (config.Values.ReleaseVersion < 1.0) {
    template = 'partials/pagebeta.html';
  } 
  else {
    template = 'partials/page.html';
  }
});
templateUrl: template
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your templateUrl depends on the value computed asynchronously you can't use the directive's `templateUrl` property anymore and you will be obliged to use lower-level API, namely `$http` and `$compile`.

Roughly what you need to do (only possible in the linking function) is to retrieve template's content using `$http` (don't forget to involve `$templateCache`!) and then compile template's content "manually".

It might sound like it is a lot of work but in practice it is rather straightforward. I would suggest having a look at the `ngInclude` directive [sources](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngInclude.js) where this pattern is used.